# How to keep forest plot from getting cut off?

Tags: r, plot

I am creating several forest plots, but they are all getting cut off knit the RMD. Reproducible example:

```
author = c("aaaaaaaaaa", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x")
Ne = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Me = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
SDe = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Nc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Mc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
SDc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)

df = data.frame(author, Ne, Me, SDe, Nc, Mc, SDc)

m.cont <- meta::metacont(n.e = Ne,
                   mean.e = Me,
                   sd.e = SDe,
                   n.c = Nc,
                   mean.c = Mc,
                   sd.c = SDc,
                   studlab = author,
                   data = df,
                   sm = "SMD",
                   method.smd = "Hedges",
                   fixed = FALSE,
                   random = TRUE,
                   method.tau = "REML",
                   hakn = TRUE,
                   title = "Example")

meta::forest.meta(m.cont, 
            sortvar = TE,
            predict = TRUE, 
            print.tau2 = FALSE,
            leftlabs = c("Author", "g", "SE"),
            xlim = "symmetric")
```

I know I can get the full figures through running block without knitting and then expanding the figure, but I'd like these plots to be presentable within the knit html doc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the width and height of your figure in the chunk header.

````
---
title: "Testing"
output: html_document
---

```{r,fig.width = 10,fig.height=10}
#above this is where you can add dimensions
author = c("aaaaaaaaaa", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x")
Ne = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Me = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
SDe = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Nc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
Mc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)
SDc = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5)

df = data.frame(author, Ne, Me, SDe, Nc, Mc, SDc)

m.cont <- meta::metacont(n.e = Ne,
                         mean.e = Me,
                         sd.e = SDe,
                         n.c = Nc,
                         mean.c = Mc,
                         sd.c = SDc,
                         studlab = author,
                         data = df,
                         sm = "SMD",
                         method.smd = "Hedges",
                         fixed = FALSE,
                         random = TRUE,
                         method.tau = "REML",
                         hakn = TRUE,
                         title = "Example")

meta::forest.meta(m.cont, 
                  sortvar = TE,
                  predict = TRUE, 
                  print.tau2 = FALSE,
                  leftlabs = c("Author", "g", "SE"),
                  xlim = "symmetric",)

```
````

When you knit it you should then get:
[image: output]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I was using fig_width, fig.width is working now.

Comment: Glad to help! If you feel that this answered the question you can mark it as "answered" by clicking the green check mark by the upvotes. That takes it out of the unanswered questions group (and give me credit for my answer).